# The arms or arms

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I'd like to know if we should say:

> Anne came with ***arms*** full of flower

or

> Anne came with ***the arms*** full of flowers .

Comment: Well, I would say 'with _her_ arms full'.

Comment: I suggest that "with arms full of flowers" is also (idiomatically) correct, and also has a subtle connotation of surprise at the large quantity.

Comment: I'll amplify Kate Bunting's comment: In English, unlike many other languages, most body-parts are referred to with possessives: _I banged **my** head_, _She lifted **her** arm_, _they opened **their** eyes_, _with **my** arm round him_. It would not be idiomatic to use _the_ in any of those examples.

Answer (score 1):

If you pluralise 'flowers' your first example is okay, although we are more likely to say:

> Anne came with **her** arms full of flowers.

We do have the compound word "armful" which means as much as the arm or arms can carry. There is no plural form of this word. So you could say:

> Anne came with **an armful** of flowers.

Your second example isn't right, as we would not say "the arms" about a named person's arms that way.

Answer (score 1):

From [WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/the-plural-of/armful.html#:%7E:text=The%20plural%20form%20of%20armful%20is%20armfuls%20or%20armsful.&text=William%20decided%20to%20bring%20her,of%20syringa%2C%20armfuls%20of%20syringa.)
***What is the plural of armful**?*...

[image]

Where "an armful" means "the amount which can be held by an arm". Hence

> *Anne came with **armsful / armfuls** of flowers* (note ***-ful***, not ***-full***, and plural ***flowers***)

Some dictionaries will explicitly mention both plural forms for ***Xful*** words *(fistful, forkful, spoonful, tablespoonful,...),* but you'll always find a few pedants arguing for or against the position of the pluralising 's' in one or all such words.

Presumably Anne has two arms, so I don't see why she can't be carrying plural ***armfuls*** (or ***armsful***) of flowers. But I will just mention that the Google Chrome spell-checker takes it upon itself to underline my second choice there.

---

TL;DR: I'm relatively tolerant of "non-standard" language variants from others, and I'm also highly confident in my own linguistic competence even where it conflicts with dictionaries, so *I personally* have nothing against ***armsful***, and will defend that position against anyone.

But actually, you might find quite a *lot* of people (still "pedants", imho) who insist only ***armfuls*** is valid. So you might want to bear that in mind if you don't want to be labelled "ignorant".

Comment: I don't remember my thinking at the time, but I kinda doubt I'd have baldly asserted "most dictionaries" like that without any support other than my own expectations. What I *might* have done back then (which I've just done now) is enter **dictionary armsful armfuls** into a Google search.  The first two results www.learnersdictionary.com AND https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/armful show snippets including *"plural **armfuls** also **armsful**"* on the Google homepage. But the *next* two (Cambridge & Collins) *don't* include ***armsful***, so I'll edit my answer text accordingly.